# How to reverse columns in reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass, next.js, reactstrap

I want to implement something like this

on Desktop : A B
on Mobile : B
A

I have tried using using react strap grid system but couldn't find a way to make it work
Im using reactstrap library in nextjs ,

Answer (score 1):

Reactstrap also provides a bootstrap lib

which is imported in _app.js as so

```
import "../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

now as it also support the latest version of bootstrap , which is bootstrap 4

col-sm-push-4 , col-sm-pull-4 classes are deprecated and cannot be used.

Bootstrap 4 provides other flex classes to make it responsive

here's the solution

```
 <Container fluid>
        <Row className="flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
        <Col className="col-md-8">
          <h1>AAAAA</h1>
       </Col>
       <Col className="col-md-4">
       <h1>BBBBB</h1>

       </Col>
        </Row>
</Container>
```

Comment: Css flex `flex-direction: row-reverse;` will help you